# exit code of the command **before** last?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, exit

I'm running a script within a script, release.sh and caller.sh (caller.sh calls release.sh). Both are bash.

release.sh contains a bunch of conditions with 'exit 1' for errors.

caller.sh contains a line that goes "./release.sh", then a checks for the exit code of release.sh - if $? is greater than 0 then echo "release.sh screwed up" and exits.

```
./release.sh
        if [ $? -gt "0" ] ; then
            echo "release_manager exited with errors, please see the release log."
            exit 1
        else 
            echo "release manager is done." 
        fi
```

Recently I've decided to log release.sh, and so the line in caller.sh goes:

```
./release.sh 2>&1 | tee release.txt
```

Because of the pipe, $? is the exit code of 'tee release.txt' , which always comes out as 0, regardless of the previous command :-(

I have to check for release.sh errors and stop the caller from proceeding, but I also really need that log.

Is there a way to get the exit code of the command **before** last?
Or a different way to log the release script in the same command?

I'm not really in charge of release.sh, I'd rather not change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using bash you can set in the script the option:

```
set -o pipefail
```

> The pipeline's return status is the value of the last (rightmost) command
>   to exit with a non-zero status, or zero if all commands exit successfully.

Alternatively, immediately after the piped command you can look at builtin variable value `${PIPESTATUS[0]}` for the exit code of the first command in the pipe.

> PIPESTATUS: An array variable containing a list of exit
>    status values from the processes in the most-recently-executed foreground
>    pipeline (which may contain only a single command).

Comment: I like the ${PIPESTATUS[0]}, cheers!

Comment: Note that `pipefail` is also in `mksh`, `ksh93` and `zsh`. `$PIPESTATUS` is bash-specific but was inspired from `zsh`'s similar `$pipestatus` array.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest rewriting it like that:

```
./release.sh > release.txt 2>&1
```

and then

```
echo $?
```

would return the correct exit status