# How to get either the last line of output or the exit code

Tags: bash, scripting

I am writing an automated homework grader in bash. The grader compiles a program and runs it. If the program fails to compile or fails to run (e.g. due to a segmentation fault) the grade should be a fixed small number, e.g. 5. Otherwise, the grade is the last line output by the program.

To get the last line, I can do:

```
grade=$( ./a.out | tail -1 )
```

But this always gives an exit code of 0, even if a.out fails to run (e.g. not found), so I cannot tell whether the program failed to exist.

Another option is to use a temporary file:

```
./a.out > temp
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
  grade=0
else
  grade=$( tail -1 temp )
fi
```

However, this might be problematic if there are many different processes doing the same simultaneously. Even with  one process, it is wasteful to keep all output in a file (the output might be large) when I only need the last line.

Is there a solution that does not use a temporary file?

Comment: Any objections to running it twice? Once to ensure a zero exit code, subsequently for the output?

Comment: @JeffSchaller This is also an option, but it is quite inefficient, especially when there are many simultanous submissions. Consider 100 students submitting simultaneously. There is a noticeable difference between 100 runs and 200 runs.

Comment: In `bash`, you can use `PIPESTATUS` instead of `$?`: `exit 13 | tail -n1; echo ${PIPESTATUS[0]}`

Comment: @mosvy strangely, this does not work when I capture the output into a variable: *** $ grade=$( ./a.out | tail -1 )
*** bash: ./a.out: No such file or directory
*** $ echo ${PIPESTATUS[0]}
*** 0

Comment: command substitutions are run in a subshell; you should check the PIPESTATUS inside that subshell: `grade=$(./a.out | tail -1; test ${PIPESTATUS[0]} = 0 || echo 5)`

Comment: I found a different solution: "set -o pipefail" at the start of the script (as recommended here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/267031/16569 ) makes the return value of the pipe nonzero if one part of the pipe fails. This works even in the command substitution.

Comment: Or even better, do the test before the tail ;-) `grade=$({ ./a.out || echo 5; } | tail -n1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
grade=$( { ./a.out 2>/dev/null || echo 0; } | tail -n 1 )
```

This would try to execute `./a.out` and then add a line with a single `0` to its output if that program exited with a non-zero exit status or failed to execute at all.  The `0` would be caught by `tail -n 1` and placed in `$grade`.

If `./a.out` executed correctly and terminated with a zero exit status, the `echo` would not be triggered.

Remove the redirection of standard error to `/dev/null` if you are interested in seeing diagnostic messages related to running `./a.out`.

Change the `0` to `"$?"` to get the exit code instead.  To be able to differentiate a number from an error, you may want to use `NaN` instead, or some error string.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem boils down to: "I want to get the last line of output AND detect abnormal exit without using temporary files". In that case, `set -o pipefail` is your friend.

Here's a simple script that executes its arguments and records the last line of the output on normal exit:

```
#!/bin/bash

[[ -x $1 ]] || {
    echo >&2 "Usage ${0##*/} <PROGRAM> [ARG1] ..."
    exit 1
}

set -o pipefail
program=$1
shift;
x=$($program "$@" | tail -1)

if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "Pass: $x"
else
    echo "Fail: $?"
fi
```

I'll leave the problem of assigning a grade to you.